# Context.createSubcontext throws exception javax.naming.OperationNotSupportedException

Tags: java, exception, rmi, jndi

I have registered JNDI. When I invoke Conrext.createSubcontext I get the exception:

```
javax.naming.OperationNotSupportedException
at com.sun.jndi.rmi.registry.RegistryContext.createSubcontext(RegistryContext.java:226)
at com.sun.jndi.toolkit.url.GenericURLContext.createSubcontext(GenericURLContext.java:390)
at javax.naming.InitialContext.createSubcontext(InitialContext.java:464)
```

Implementation looks like:

```
 Registry reg = LocateRegistry.createRegistry(1099);

 Properties properties = new Properties();
 properties.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContextFactory");
 properties.put(Context.URL_PKG_PREFIXES, "org.jboss.naming:org.jnp.interfaces");
 properties.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "localhost:1099");

 InitialContext initialContextcontext = new InitialContext(properties);

 ic.createSubcontext("rmi://localhost/java:jdbc");
```

Please suggest where I missed.

Answer (score 1):

The provider does not support sub-contexts. the RMI Registry itself doesn't: it provides a one-dimensional namespace.

Possibly you are using the wrong provider for JNP.

Comment: maybe you could suggest some links or some example? looks I have tried everything but without success :(

Comment: Err, the JNP documentation? You can't have tried 'everything', can you? Otherwise you would have found a solution.